# Load .zshrc file in ssh server specific to the connecting hostname

Tags: ssh, configuration

I want to source a certain `.zshrc` file on the remote host when connecting to it with my computer. With any other connecting machine I need some other default configs. For example similar lines could be present in the `.zshrc` file on the remote host:

```
if [[ connecting_host_is_mypc ]]; then
  # do something
  ...
else
  # do something else
  ...
fi
```

I suppose I should bind this to the specific public key, what's the neatest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to SSH server, it sets you the environment variables based with the information where you are connecting from. This information is stored in variable `SSH_CONNECTION`, as described in the manual page for `ssh`:

> `SSH_CONNECTION`
>
> Identifies the client and server ends of the connection.  The variable contains four space-separated values: client IP address, client port number, server IP address, and server port number.

Comment: I know about those variables, but the local IP address is dynamic, so I can't use it for my purpose as it changes every time and also depending on the network I am connected to. I need a unique identifier.

Comment: If you need a unique identifier of your computer (in your rc file), creating some environment variable locally, configuring your client to send it (`SendEnv`) and server to accept it (`AcceptEnv`). It should do the job